# Is there an alternative to libmediainfo?

Tags: c++, c, c++11, ffmpeg, multimedia

In my upcoming application I’d like to get information about an A/V file. libmediainfo’s dev doc is quite hard-to-study for me (and it uses wchar_t -.-").

Is there a **better** alternative?

**Acceptance criteria:**

- platform independent (I’m going to dev on GNU OS)
- works w/ C++11
- supports 8bit (char) for **all** strings and I/O (doesn’t require wchar_t) w/o re-compiling the whole library.

Maybe I’d prefer libav if its [doc](http://ffmpeg.org/libavformat.html) weren’t so poor.

Comment: you could parse the output of `ffmpeg -i input` ...

Comment: `ffmpeg`’s output is **human** readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ultimate solution: `avprobe`